# Testing whether a value is in a set and assigning variable

Tags: python

Given this set and an input GET parameter that indicates a chosen fruit

```
fruit = {'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'}
```

Is there a compact way to do this in one line in python?

```
chosen = request_obj.get('fruit', '')

if chosen not in fruit:
    chosen = ''
```

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. Is this a set or a dict? Your example is neither.

Comment: @jterrace: `{}` can be used to create sets since Python 2.7. Unless you're talking about something else?

Comment: @jterrace: the syntax is valid in python 2.7 and up.

Comment: I corrected your `fruit` example; it is a `set`, not a `dict` and the contents are presumably strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
>>> fruit = {'apple','banana','orange','pear'}
>>> d = {'fruit': 'apple'}
>>> d['fruit'] if 'fruit' in d and d['fruit'] in fruit else ''
'apple'
>>> d['fruit'] = 'watermellon'
>>> d['fruit'] if 'fruit' in d and d['fruit'] in fruit else ''
''
```

Honestly, though, I think what you have is more readable and the better choice.

Comment: I think this is the reverse of what the OP is looking for.

Comment: How so? I thought this was exactly what the OP wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do -

```
fruit = {'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'pear'}
input_get_param = 'some_other_fruit'

if input_get_param in fruit:
    chosen = input_get_param
    print 'pear is in the set'
else:
    chosen = ''
```

I am preferring first a set lookup since python `set` implementation uses a hashtable as it's underlying data structure. This explains the O(1) membership checking, since looking up an item in a hashtable is an O(1) operation, on average. So lookup is fairly cheap.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> fruit = {'apple','banana','orange','pear'}
>>> d = {'fruit': 'apple'}
>>> chosen = '' if d.get('fruit','') not in fruit else d.get('fruit','')
>>> chosen
'apple'
>>> d['fruit'] = 'watermellon'
>>> chosen = '' if d.get('fruit','') not in fruit else d.get('fruit','')
>>> chosen
''
```